# [admin-on-rest]: Search only when search button is pressed

Tags: admin-on-rest

this is related to admin-on-rest reactJs based framework.

I need some help/pointers on enabling search only when a search button is pressed. I need to collect multiple inputs from the user and finally push a query via REST Api to the back-end when a search button is clicked.

The query searches a very large DB set and I don't want to push queries to back-end as user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do.

You need to write a custom Redux Form component. Something like below. I haven't tested this code. But I hope you get the general idea. You will also need to handle all the props that are passed down by Redux Form to your component. Take a look at the Redux Form docs. Also take a look at  the TextInput component of Admin-On-Rest in the source code.

```
const ENTER_KEY = 13;

class RenderTextField extends Component {
  handleKeyDown = (event) => {
       switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case ENTER_KEY:
            this.props.input.onChange(this.state.searchQuery);
            break;
        default: 
            this.setState({this.searchQuery: event.target.value})
    }
  }
  render() {
     return (<input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        //You will need to look at the ReduxForm docs and handle all the props that are passed to every ReduxForm component.
     />)
  }
}
```

4) You can also use material UI components with ReduxForm.

http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/material-ui/